# Transferring shadow from raw footage to render VFX

Tags: objects, compositing-nodes

I Have footage of my hand moving over a wall and it casts a shadow on the wall. In Blender, I am putting VFX objects on that wall. How can I transfer the shadow from the real wall onto the CG one that my VFX objects are on?

Comment: If the wall is key-able then you need to remove the wall and leave your hand. Then use the hand alpha channel and offset it to simulate a shadow.

Comment: is it possible if the wall is not key-able?

Comment: Well how are you putting the CG objects on the wall but under your hand?

Comment: I masked my hand and the object on the wall has an alpha channel. I cant project the mask of my hand onto the wall because the angle of my arm isn't close to the shape of my shadow. I could ask the shadow and project it but that would produce a mediocre result and it would take a lot of time. Is that what I have to do?

Comment: Could you post a setup of hand and wall or other elements? For example how are you superimposing the hand? Are you using the compositor or making the hand a 3D texture mapped object? Does your hand change shape during animation? Could you post a frame of your hand footage?

Comment: Possibly related solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/633/when-integrating-live-action-footage-and-cg-how-to-make-proper-shadows-for-acto?rq=1