# How do you create an infinite ground plane?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

How would you make a ground plane that goes on forever?

Here is an example, but it is from a very very old version of blender.
http://vimeo.com/8107842

Comment: Are you using cycles or blender internal?

Comment: cycles and blender 2.7

Comment: Use a plane where the material is a mix of transparent and diffuse, and the mix factor is the `Is Shadow Ray` output from the lightpaths node.

Comment: @someonewithpc If that is the ideal solution, you should add it as an answer.

Comment: I can't get it to work, though...

Comment: @someonewithpc Cycles will need a shadow catcher material for that to work..

Comment: @gandalf3 That was the purpose of the Diffuse shader.

Comment: It's a feature which cycles doesn't have yet

Answer (score 7):

## For Cycles:

I don't think this really is possible in cycles currently, however you probably don't actually need an infinite plane.

The camera will only render objects up to a finite distance away (*end clipping* value), so your plane only needs to be larger than this value to appear "infinite".

To do this, enable *Limits* in *Camera settings > Display* to display a line visualizing the start and end clipping of the camera:

[image]

As long as your end clipping value is reasonably high and your plane is larger than it, the plane will appear reasonably infinite:

[image]

---

If you instead want an effect like in iKlsR's answer, you'll have to do some compositing with renderlayers.

1. Move your diffuse ground plane to another layer
2. Create another renderlayer and set the layer to the layer on which your ground plane is, then enable the *shadow*, *AO*, and *Diffuse indirect* passes:

   [image]

   *In this example, the ground plane is on layer 2 and the rest of the scene is on layer 1*.
3. Enable *Environment* on the original renderlayer, which should also be set to only render the layer with all the objects *besides* the ground plane.
4. Enable *Transparent* in *Render settings > Film*
5. Composite:

   [image]

[**Example .blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32185)

Answer (score 4):

## For Blender Internal Only:

From my answer on [How to make a model cast shadows onto the world texture/background?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background/).

Basically all you need is a plane to catch the shadow of the object(s) on it.

A quick way to achieve this using the **internal renderer** is to add a plane, select it and add a new material, in the material settings under *Shadow*, enable *Shadows Only*.

[image]

Next, you can optionally enable transparency, use *Z Transparency* and use the alpha slider to control the strength/darkness of the shadow.

[image]

To further enhance this and add to the realism, you can enable *Ambient Occlusion* and use a blend sky *(for simple renders)*. It is also worth noting that the shadow you get is dependent on the type of lamp and world settings you use in some cases, in the image below I am using a sun lamp with ray shadow enabled and I also have Environment lighting turned on, this softens the shadow and its harder to control but gives a nicer subtle effect.

[image]

Here I am using a sun lamp and a point lamp with Environment lighting off, with this setup, I can easier adjust the opacity of the shadow with the transparency setting.

[image]

Comment: Are you using cycles and blender 2.7? I don't have a shadows option under the materials section.

Comment: This only works for Blender Internal.

Comment: @spuder Ah, this is for Blender internal only. When people don't mention the engine, that is what is assumed.

Comment: @iKlsR I always assume cycles :P