# Plane to only reflect object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

So I'm using cycles and I would like the plane that my object is sitting on to be invisible apart from the reflection from the object. So all you see is empty space, the object and its reflection and no plane. Thanks in advance

Comment: Related, [How do you create an infinite ground plane?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-do-you-create-an-infinite-ground-plane)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to make the plane invisible apart from reflection ,uncheck all the options in **Ray Visibility** except **Glossy**

[image]

this will make the object appear only as a reflection on objects with glossy shader

[image]

render :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new renderlayer. The groundplane keeps the reflective material, but the object gets a white emission material. Hide all lights and environments. This gives you a black and white mask for the object and reflection that you can use with your beauty renderlayer.

Comment: Can you add some more detail? Where can I find render layers? How do I then use this render layer in an existing or new node setup?

Comment: Yeah I don't really understand. I'm not new to Blender itself but I'm new to render layers etc.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not in front of a computer right now. The wiki gives me an internal server error, and the new manual seems rather useless on that topic. Maybe later