# Hide object while keeping light reflection

Tags: rendering

Does anyone know a way to make an object get hidden/invisible from the camera while keeping light reflection on it? Something like a " shadow catcher ", but it only shows light instead. Thanks!

Comment: [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66026/only-render-reflection-of-an-object-on-an-invisible-object#75626](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66026/only-render-reflection-of-an-object-on-an-invisible-object#75626)