# How to mix mesh and real footage in compositor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, video, tracking

How can I mix real footage and a 3D model that I've animated? Can this be done with the Compositor?

See the orange rectangle in the picture below for an example of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Ths question is not much clear... try elaborating a bit more on what you wish to achieve...

Comment: mix a real footage and 3D Animation Mesh.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking, but you might want to take a look at [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background) for some related advice.

Comment: a real footage , dissolve a 3d Mesh

Comment: Sure it can be done :-)
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender