# Glass, transparent to background video

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency

Im trying to render a glass on a transparent background(video sequence).

Problem: 
The transparet background that shows in the glass, is my "Shadow"plane. (from my layer 2.

I would like the background to be from my video, and not background from layer 2. (3d World)

I have not found any information about this.
My node setup for my glass is:

(Glass BSDF, Trabsparet BSDF,Fresnel)->  (Mix shader)-> (Material Output(Surface)

[image]

I've setup my two layers.

1) For object:(Glass object, and a smoke object inside my glassbowl...)

2) For shadows: Plane for casting shadows onto my transparent background(video)

And my lights thats on both layers.

The white background shown, is my glassbowl is the "Shadow"plane in layer two, the smal sphere is my smoke object in layer one.
As you see the video background is not showing on my glassobject.

Ive made my glass transparent for my 3d world not my video

[image]

Im not alowed to add more than two photos beacuase i dont have enough "skills"/ Badges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Related answer.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background)

To only gain the reflection and refraction in the sphere, you have to simulate your environment.

1. Roughly model the shapes of your environment.
2. Assign a material to the environment object. Use and **Emission BSDF**. Input the background image as a texture with **Window** *Texture Coordinate*.
   [image]
3. In the viewport, the image will be mapped to the object according to its position in the (2D) window. From camera view, this will look correct.
   [image]
4. Since the camera is not supposed to render the environment object, turn off **Camera** in the object cycles settings.
   [image]

[image]

From [BlenderGuru](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-input-encyclopedia/):

> Just like with the Camera coordinates above, the Window coordinates
>   are not used very often. In the past I’ve used this to stick camera
>   footage onto a plane behind my scene, so that some glass materials
>   would correctly refract what’s behind them and the models would be
>   more accurately lit by the environment in the footage, but that’s
>   about it.

The [render](https://s3.amazonaws.com/blenderguru.com/uploads/2015/06/07_window_usage-673x449.jpg) will be more realistic if you add more geometric and have more than just the window frame textured since the reflection of a glass sphere will reflect 360°.