# Putting objects into an environment

Tags: texturing

I'm a complete beginner to Blender, this question is about putting objects into an environment

Basically, I don't know exactly how to get an object to have color and be in an environment. I have a model of a phone in right now and it's just grey.

Comment: This is a good place to start with Blender https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background/26686#26686 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69862#69862~