# Trying to produce a shadow that is exported with an object

Tags: shadows, shadowcatcher

Potentially an impossible task, but feels like it should be able to be done. Is there a way to cast a shadow onto a transparent shadowcatcher, than export the .glb file so that when I use the image in swift/ios the 3d model's shadow is attached?

Comment: Im not experienced with .glb, but have you tried to Bake shadow pass to use it as alpha texture?

Comment: I have tried to bake in a few different ways - I'm pretty unfamiliar with blender as whole myself so I'm probably doing something wrong lol

Comment: There is a trillion of tuts with this topic ... try to search some.

Comment: I have, and I have followed a few with no success, unfortunately. I'll try some more again.

Comment: What have you tried and where tut failed for you? Edit your original question that fits your current issue ... thanks.

Comment: Wonder if you could do it this way? -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background/72354#72354

Answer (score 0):

what I ended up doing to get around this, it's probably not the best approach, and feels a bit like cheating — I just duplicated the bottom layer of the image and painted it black, and exported it so that I could have a static shadow with no light necessary. It looks like a shadow at the very least. Appreciate all the help!